# How to test for NO logged in users in Win10

Tags: windows, windows-10

When a user is logged in, they can easily use quser.exe to see all logged in users.

I want to run a scheduled task (running as SYSTEM) at various times, and one function in the script has the potential to do something that could kick off a reboot.  Thus, before that function runs, I need to first check if any users are logged in.

In Win7, I have been checking the output of:

```
quser.exe 2>&1
```

for a "No user exists" string, and that works great.  It is not working in Win10 however.

The output of that same command in Win10 when nobody is logged in appears to be blank/empty.  An empty value seems like a risky thing to test against because there are a lot of possible error sources for an empty string leading to a user experiencing an unexpected reboot.  **I cannot use a notification and countdown** to warn the user.

Is there any other (automated, obviously) way to verify that no users are currently logged in?

Comment: You could get a list of processes running I the machine and look at each one's owning username, excluding those owned by SYSTEM, services, etc. Not very elegant though...

Comment: Can you install PsLoggedOn on the client computers? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psloggedon

Comment: On some, maybe, but generally, no.  I'm trying to find a built-in method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `quser` (i.e. query user) and relying on a valid, empty return, a better solution seems to be with `qwinsta` (i.e. query sessions).

Basically, query for all sessions, and parse the return for user names.  Sessions running under services or SYSTEM don't have a  username.  So in PowerShell:

```
$qwinstaOut = & "$env:windir\system32\QWinSta.exe"
if (-not $qwinstaOut) {
   $UserSessions = "unknown"
} else {
   $UserSessions = $qwinstaOut[1..($qwinstaOut.count-1)] | % {$_.substring(19)} | ? {$_ -match "^\w"}
}
# If there are no sessions with a username, this must be running as SYSTEM
if (-not $UserSessions) {
...
```

If the variable `$userSessions` is blank, no users are logged in.  If it is not blank, either users are logged in or there was an error.  Not perfect, but safer.